# NSMutableURLRequest cannot connect to local network

Tags: objective-c, ios, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I am using AFNetworking to connect from an iOS v6.0 app to my local Cold Fusion 8 server, not on the same machine but on the same network and the connection times out.  When I use an external public server it works fine.

I have tried the connection via IP address and it doesn't work.
I have tried an entry in the hosts file assigning a domain name to the IP address and this doesn't work either.  Please see the error below.
I can however connect via a web browser just fine.
Also, the server side files are exactly the same.  Versions of Cold Fusion are the same.  The only difference that I can find are the public server is Win2003 with IIS6 and the local server is Windows7 with IIS7.

Any thoughts on why this would not work on a local network.  Makes local development kind of difficult.

Here is the relevant code:

```
// load params
NSMutableDictionary *myParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; 
[myParams setValue:@"Hello" forKey:@"Parameter1"];
[myParams setValue:@"There" forKey:@"Parameter2"];

   // Load the base URL into a URL object
   // Changing this to an external public server works fine
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mylocalmachine.com/"];

// Create HTTP client and init with base url
AFHTTPClient *myHttpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

// POST request to path with the parameters
NSMutableURLRequest *myRequest = [myHttpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"myfile.cfm" parameters:myParams];

// Block response from the HTTP client request and pass it back to the calling object
AFJSONRequestOperation *myOperation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:myRequest
                                                                                      success:^(NSURLRequest *mySuccessRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse *mySuccessResponse, id mySuccessJSON)
    {
        // PROCESS THE SUCCESS RESPONSE;
    }
                                                                                      failure:^(NSURLRequest *myFailureRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse *myFailureResponse, NSError *myFaliureError, id myFailureJSON)
    {
        // PROCESS THE FAILURE RESPONSE... AFTER 60 seconds the system will fallout to this block.



    }];

// Create a queue object
NSOperationQueue *myQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

// Add the operation object to the queue
[myQueue addOperation:myOperation];
```

The following is the error I get print the myFailureError object

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x8481000 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://www.mylocalmachine.int/myfile.cfm, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://www.mylocalmachine.int/myfile.cfm, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0x9189e20 "The request timed out."}
```

Update----
I believe I have narrowed the issue down to what I beleive to be an issue with the iPhone simulator accessing IIS 7. It will access previous versions of IIS on the same network using the same code no problem. 
The problem may be in the iPhone Simulator's User-Agent.  I have tried to find a way to change the iPhone Simulator's User-Agent or allow the User-Agent in IIS 7 but can not seem to figure it out. The User-Agent the iPhone Simulator 6 is presenting is (iPhone Simulator; ios 6.0; Scale/2.00).

Does anyone know how to either allow this User-Agent on IIS 7 or change the User-Agent in the iPhone simulator?

Has anyone else seen this issue?
Thanks in advance,
Ed

Update----

Hi Everyone
Ok so I figured out how to change the User-Agent and Content-Type using the NSMutableURLRequest.  I changed these to match what the browser would send, FireFox browser, and tried again to no avail.  I still believe there is an issue with the configuration of IIS 7.5 but I can not find it...
Thanks for anyones help!!!
Ed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue.  I will post what the resolution was to hopefully help someone else with a similar issue.
Turns out the problem was AVG installed on the system that was running IIS 7.  It was a difficult issue to determine because any other system could access the web server with out any problems.  It was only specific with the iPhone simulator accessing the system running IIS7.  Even Safari or FireFox running on the same Mac would work just fine.  Now what within AVG was causing the problem... That is yet to be determined.
I truly hope this helps someone along the way!

Answer (score 0):

please try to remove last 2 lines of code  and write

remove this

```
NSOperationQueue *myQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[myQueue addOperation:myOperation];
```

add this instead

```
[myoperation start];
```

and also write failure:nil before that ending square bracket(]) like

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *myOperation = [AFJSONRequestOperation    JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:myRequest
                                                                                   success:^(NSURLRequest *mySuccessRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse *mySuccessResponse, id mySuccessJSON)
{
    // PROCESS THE SUCCESS RESPONSE;
}
                                                                                  failure:^(NSURLRequest *myFailureRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse *myFailureResponse, NSError *myFaliureError, id myFailureJSON)
{
    // PROCESS THE FAILURE RESPONSE... AFTER 60 seconds the system will fallout to this block.

}failure:nil];
```

let me know is it working or not...!!!!
Happy Coding!!!!!!

Comment: Hi Nirav, thank you for your assistance, however, these edits did not work.  I have narrowed it down to what I beleive to be an issue with the iPhone simulator accessing IIS 7.  It will access previous versions of IIS on the same network.  I have tried to find a way to change the iPhone Simulator's User-Agent or allow the User-Agent in IIS 7 but can not seem to figure it out.  The User-Agent the iPhone Simulator 6 is presenting is (iPhone Simulator; ios 6.0; Scale/2.00).  Does anyone know how to either allow this User-Agent on IIS 7 or change the User-Agent in the iPhone simulator? Thanks